# How to strengthen the plastic thread for repeated attaching/detaching of a garden hose?

Tags: repair, hose

My garden hose rack-mount, my shop-vac, etc.. all have a plastic thread to attach a garden hose.

I try hard to hit the thread just right, but sometimes I miss.

This leads me to wonder if I'm not unduly shortening the life of all these devices by not strengthening their plastic tip.

Does there exist a minuscule extension that I would thread permanently on each such plastic tip to turn it into a brass tip one? What name should I use to ask for this gadget at the hardware store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called "a very short hose". :) You can make your own with parts commonly available at hardware and big-box stores.

Alternatively, install a simple valve, an elbow, or a backflow preventer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Be aware that extending a plastic connection with a rigid part adds torque stress to that connection. Use caution to not lever on it.

Comment: This solution also applies to electrical and electronic cables; very short extension cables (male→female) are often dubbed "port savers" as they reduce the wear on the device's port.

Comment: @sleblanc Fantastic.. There is indeed something on the market called "USB port saver". This would combat the tendency of laptop manufacturers to leave the USB ports as part of the motherboard (and hence make them all but unrepairable, but maybe forced replacement *is* their objective). As isherwood describes, this may not entirely solve the problem, since any bending will aggravate the stress on the main board.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of a threaded connector go for a quick disconnect.

The connectors will screw on the existing threads and you can then connect by pushing in and disconnect bu pulling the tab.

Comment: This sounds like a nice option, but I can't figure out exactly what to look for. Could you provide a search keyword?

Comment: @Calaf "quick disconnect gardenhose"

Comment: Thanks. Well, duh, silly me. Of course the coupling on all garden hoses will need to be modified as well. That's the better, but not "backwards compatible" solution. +1. Starters, take note.